# Firefox Developer ignoring font-weight

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts

I'm using the newest Firefox Developer Edition (78.0b2). Unfortunately when trying to import a font from google-fonts with multiple weights, Firefox is ignoring the font weight where in Chrome everything works as expected.

I tried to clean cache, disable adblocker etc, nothing helps. When page initially loads I can clearly see that correct weights are applied to the fonts but then they are immediately replaced by first weight imported from google fonts.

Here is how I'm importing the fonts:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hind+Siliguri:wght@700&family=Work+Sans:wght@400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here is screenshot of how it looks like in Firefox:

[image]

Here is how it looks in Chrome:

[image]

What is even more interesting that when I open the page in Firefox but in incognito mode, the correct weights are applied. But as I said, I tried to clean cache with ctrl+f5 or ctr+shift+r but it didnt help.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: I manage to get something to work here. It turns out that the problem somehow lies in the import. When I'm importing all three Work Sans styles in one Link tag that Firefox is only recognizing the first one - so I tried to import the styles in separate Link tags and then it started working. Unfortunately this is not a solution and would like to hear if anyone of you had a similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

Closing this one, reinstalling Firefox fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues with Firefox and define everything through CSS using:

```
@supports(-moz-appearance:meterbar) and (max-width: 
768px){foo}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it seems that Firefox is ignoring `font-weight` property, you could try the following:

1. Open `about:config`
2. Check **Show only modified preferences**
3. Type `font` to show all font related settings
4. Revert them to default values.

It has worked for me.